# Embeding data from multiple sources, into a single web page

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I would like to embed in a single web page, data from multiple sources:

- social networks (facebook, twitter, linkedin, etc)
- rss feeds
- article meta tags (mainly opengraph and twitter cards)

The data can change dynamically, based on user actions (button click, or menu select, for example)

I would like to load the data using front-end tools, hopefully without any back-end. The main issues are cross origin resource sharing, and iframes hold a security risks

Is there any "proper" front-end way to handle such cases, or do I have to use back-end tools ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Focus on a particular source. What are the caresteristics of the source (public, CORS etc)? What have you tried so far? What didn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What about RSS feeds?

Comment: @de1 why too broad...? my question is on front end embeding method of 3rd party, via front end. if its not as clear I can rephrase

Comment: For social networks, I believe you can get embed codes without having to authenticate with a server but if you want to be able to modify data then you will need to develop a back end to handle that part for your application. Here is an example of the [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) which does nto require a back-end. As for iframes of course there are risks but it depends mostly on the host of the iframe. Iframes from YouTube and such are less vulnerable than a less trusted site so you have to be able to trust the source to trust the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact your question is too broad as @de1 said. I found a site that could be usefull for you [Social Media Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/social-media/). I also found a specific Plugin that can fit in some use that you need, but them all, like: [jQuery Plugin For Displaying Social Network Feed - Social Feed](https://www.jqueryscript.net/social-media/jQuery-Plugin-For-Displaying-Social-Network-Feeds-Social-Feed.html). But if you want to manage the content acordding what a user click, you must edit the script or write your own.